# How to have alternative string definition for numeric enum in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

I have a numeric enum like below.

```
enum Rating {
  Unknown = 0,
  One,
  Two,
  Three,
  Four
}
```

I need to get alternative string value of enum when I access the enum string like below.

```
var stringVal = Rating[Rating.One];
```

The above line should give me "Rating of One" instead of One.

I need to stick to numeric enums and cannot use string enums. Once solution what I could think of is to use string array like below.

```
const stringRating = ["Unknown Rating", "Rating One", "Rating is Two", "Rating is Three", "Rating is Four"];
export function toString(rating: Rating): string {
return stringValues[rating];
```

But is there a better way to achieve this in typescript?

I'm expecting something like Description attribute in c# for enums like below

```
public enum MyEnum 
{ 
  [Description("value 1")] 
  Value1, 
  [Description("value 2")]
  Value2, 
  [Description("value 3")]
  Value3
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the enum strings in a `Map` object:

```
ratingStrings = new Map<Rating,string>([
  [Rating.Unknown, "Unknown Rating"],
  [Rating.One, "Rating One"],
  [Rating.Two, "Rating is Two"],
  [Rating.Three, "Rating is Three"],
  [Rating.Four, "Rating is Four"],
]);

doSomething() {
  let str = this.ratingStrings.get(Rating.Unknown);
  ...
}
```

Alternatively, in cases where the string format is the same for all enum values, you could use a function like the following:

```
ratingToString(rating: Rating): string {
  return `Rating ${Rating[rating]}`;
}

doSomething() {
  let str = this.ratingToString(Rating.Unknown);
  ...
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g7cjzk?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for a demo of both techniques.